# Angular address autofill by google map

Tags: angular

Hey guys I have problem when I select the address from google map occasionally it shows me whole address in one field but I want that in separate filed like zip code should fit in particular filed for that I am using service can you guys help me with that .

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UOk2MSt9jBVap9MkfvFse_cSHlxRSIA1/view?usp=drivesdk

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dFnwO9WCdi0w3oA7TRBbhsR7ClssJAXT/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Your question lacks some details. How are you selecting the address from google maps? Are you using an API? Is there code you can post that shows where your problem is? Can you post some output of the occasional behaviour versus the usual?

Comment: Hey hi here is the code so you can see it

Comment: Hey can you please check and give me some advice on that please it’s urgent